# Is there a way to avoid while(true) if I need to evaluate the condition at the beginning?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am learning Java and I am following a project to simulate a ski jump tournament. Basically they want me to replicate this action:

```
The tournament begins!

Write "jump" to jump; otherwise you quit: jump

Round 1

//do something

Write "jump" to jump; otherwise you quit: jump
(continues)
```

My question is solely on the way to loop this. I know I can do this by entering a while(true) loop, and break right away if the input by the user equals "quit". However, I've read in multiple places that this is a bad practice, and instead it should be: while(condition). If I were to do that, the loop wouldn't break until after it completes the first iteration. Say:

```
String command = "placeholder";
while (!command.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nRound 1");

    }
```

If I do something like this, even if the command is "quit" it'd still do the first iteration of that loop. And if I add an if with a break, then there's no point to have the condition on the while loop. Is there a better way of doing this? should I just use a while(true) loop even though people say it's bad practice?

Comment: You could  use a 'do-while' see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: It's not a great practice--many reviewers (and many IDEs) will label while(true) as a problem, even if you know what you are doing it's not necessary and it's a distraction .

Comment: @DanielMesejo You should write that up as an answer, it's the right way to go.

Comment: You might be able to solve this issue by utilizing switch. See [Using switch statements in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018562/using-switch-statements-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: @DanielMesejo, from reading your link, the contents inside the 'do-while' loop are always performed once. So I'd still have to add an if->break so I can exit when the user inputs "quit", if I do that I think the loop would never exit because of the condition at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you can try is to use switch statement. I don't know how many conditions you have so it might not be feasible. Here is the code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = "placeholder"; // magic at this line
while (!command.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.print("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
    switch (command) {
    case "jump":
        System.out.println("\nRound 1");
        break;
    case "quit":
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This does not print "Round 1".

Since you were restrict to if-statements. There is another thing you can try and that is using [continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

**From Javadoc**

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop.

So right after you ask user input you either continue to next loop or remain in same. This can be done via an if statement. Here is the code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = "placeholder"; // magic at this line
while (!command.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
    if (command.equals("quit"))
        continue;
    System.out.println("\nRound 1");
}
```

It is kinda like break but instead of exiting the loop altogether it evaluates the condition.

Comment: This is interesting and it seems like it does what I need it to do. I'm mostly asking this question from a conceptual point of view, so I'm still wondering something. Is doing this different than a while(true) with a break? I believe in this case, the condition given to the while loop is never reached, since there are breaks for each case.

Comment: @leonardo `break` just breaks out of `switch` not the `while loop` so it does reaches the condition. Try entering something besides "jump" or "quit" and see what happens.

Comment: oh! I see what you mean now. I think this is exactly what I need. I am pretty sure at this point the course expects me to do a simple if->break but I am kind of trying to get ahead of things and understand good/bad practices. I will try this! thank you so much!

Comment: @leonardo Please consider accepting the answer that best solved your problem by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: will do! I thought that's what the up arrow meant.

Comment: yes it doesn't let me. I've appointed your answer with the check mark. I think it is the best way to do what I was trying to do. However, I ran into a problem because netbeans tells me that string in switch are not supported in sourse 1.6. It says to use source 7 or higher to support it. However, I don't know if I can fix this as I am using the IDE as downloaded from the university of helsinki page.

Comment: @leonardo see this [(use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch) error;Netbeans 7.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110808/use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-strings-in-switch-errornetbeans-7-1-2)

Comment: Yes, I am able to do this. But I asked the course chatroom and they said that while it won't break anything, the server won't accept it. Sometimes it can be kind of strict in how you solve the problems and I think it's not expecting us to use the switch.

Comment: @leonardo Is there a point where user can exit after choosing jump? I am adding another thing that might work for you.

Comment: @Goion so I confirmed, I am not allowed to use String on Switch because the tests are old and don't support it. It's not a big deal, I can still do it with the if->break so I don't over complicate myself. In the program, the user either chooses jump or quit, if he chooses jump the simulation for a round of the ski jumping tournament happens, after that is done it asks the user again to see if another round will be done or not. Appreciate all the help! I always take a lot longer in these problems cause I try to think of all the possible cases and end up going down the rabbit hole lol

Comment: @leonardo In early CS class it is a struggle because you are not allowed to use a lot of thing. I remember in my CS class my professor used to hate `break` in `loops` or `if statement`. When you are in industry no one asks you to do such things then you can really focus on improving your code habits. Anyways do check the edit I made.

Comment: yes I definitely struggle with that, except I am learning on my own following that course so there's a lot of times where I just stop and think what is a good or bad way of doing things. I just checked your edit and I do like it, I'm going to try and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop condition should intuitively be `command.equals("jump")`. All you need to do is to make sure the while loop always executes at least one iteration. One way to do this is to make the initial value of `command` `"jump"`:

```
String command = "jump"; // magic at this line
while (command.equals("jump")) {
    System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nRound 1");

}
```

Alternatively, use a do...while loop, which is another kind of loop that checks the condition one after the body of the loop is executed:

```
String command;
do {
    System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nRound 1");

} while (command.equals("jump"));
```

EDIT:

If you want to break out of the loop immediately without printing "Round 1", then you need to put the `command = ...` line as the last line in the loop, and naturally the line that prints "Round 1" will go before it:

```
    while (command.equals("jump")) {
        System.out.println("\nRound 1");

        System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
        command = input.nextLine();
    }
```

However, this would cause one extra "Round 1" to be printed. You don't want the first "Round 1" to be printed, so you need to add a check. I assume in your real code you have an integer variable indicating what round it is, so you can just check that.

Comment: It still executes line `System.out.println("\nRound 1");` I believe op want to get out immediately.

Comment: I guess my issue is that, it should never reach the part where it says "Round 1" if the command is "quit". Yet if I do it that way, it'll always do so at least once and then exit.

Comment: @Sweeper I see what you mean, I don't think I can get away from running at least one round. Granted I don't believe the course expects me to account for these kind of situations at this point. But I wanted to learn a little more as I go along. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String command;

prompt();
while (!(command = input.nextLine()).equals("quit")) {
  System.out.println("\nRound 1");
  // ..
  prompt();
}

void prompt() {
    System.out.println("Write \"jump\" to jump; otherwise you quit: ");
}
```

Comment: This could work, I am simply using an if->break at the moment, but if I have some more time I'll give this a shot!